# Как преобразовать табличные данные в сгруппированный xml?

Tags: c#, sql, xml

Есть достаточно сложный SQL запрос, который возвращает вот такой набор данных.
Это магазин где есть товар, в каком количестве и по какой цене, вторая колонка это код товара.

[image: результат запроса]

Нужно получить XML примерно такого вида:

```
<tov>
  <code>253585</code>
  <name>911-ШАМПУНЬ ЛУКОВЫЙ РЕПЕЙНОЕ МАСЛО 150МЛ.</name>
  <producer>ТВИНС ТЭК</producer>
  <shops>
    <shop name="Магазин 1">
      <quantity>1,00</quantity>
      <price>144,00</price>
    </shop>
    <shop name="Магазин 3">
      <quantity>1,00</quantity>
      <price>144,00</price>
    </shop>
  </shops>
</tov>
<tov>
  <code>253587</code>
  <name>911-ШАМПУНЬ ЛУКОВЫЙ ЭКСТРАКТ КРАПИВЫ 150МЛ.</name>
  <producer>ТВИНС ТЭК</producer>
  <shop name="Магазин 5">
    <quantity>1,00</quantity>
    <price>150,00</price>
  </shop>
</tov>
<tov>
  <code>198767</code>
  <name>911-ШАМПУНЬ РЕПЕЙНЫЙ П/ВЫПАДЕНИЯ ВОЛОС 150МЛ.</name>
  <producer>ТВИНС ТЭК</producer>
  <shops>
    <shop name="Магазин 1">
      <quantity>1,00</quantity>
      <price>133,00</price>
    </shop>
    <shop name="Магазин 2">
      <quantity>1,00</quantity>
      <price>136,00</price>
    </shop>
    <shop name="Магазин 3">
      <quantity>1,00</quantity>
      <price>136,00</price>
    </shop>
    <shop name="Магазин 4">
      <quantity>1,00</quantity>
      <price>140,00</price>
    </shop>
    <shop name="Магазин 5">
      <quantity>2,00</quantity>
      <price>135,00</price>
    </shop>
  </shops>
</tov>
```

Взялся на C# разбирать результат запроса, но получается откровенная хрень, уверен есть способ простой и элегантный, посоветуйте решение.

Comment: Показанный скрин с данными и XML не соответствуют друг другу. В XML произведено объединение, которого нет в данных. Но если НЕ объединять, то экспорт должен пройти практически без дополнительных телодвижений.

Comment: `GroupBy` по коду (второй колонке).

Comment: @Akina, в том и сложность, что запрос выдает "плоский" результат который нужно разобрать по сути на несколько классов

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov GroupBy по коду (второй колонке) - уничтожит часть данных

Comment: Любой набор данных, возвращаемый SQL-сервером - всегда плоский. Требуемый результат - не плоский, двухуровневый. Вывод: необходимо получить от сервера ДВА плоских набора, и уже на клиенте заново собрать их в один двухуровневый - для чего обеспечить средствами SQL наличие признака объединения наборов. А также, с учётом особенности возврата набора данных на клиента - требуемой для облегчения обработки на клиенте сортировки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, вы получаете данные в DataTable. В примере я их заношу вручную.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ShopName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Producer", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));

dt.Rows.Add("Магазин 1", 253585, "911-ШАМПУНЬ ЛУКОВЫЙ РЕПЕЙНОЕ МАСЛО 150МЛ.", "ТВИНС ТЭК", 1, 144);
dt.Rows.Add("Магазин 3", 253585, "911-ШАМПУНЬ ЛУКОВЫЙ РЕПЕЙНОЕ МАСЛО 150МЛ.", "ТВИНС ТЭК", 1, 144);
dt.Rows.Add("Магазин 5", 253587, "911-ШАМПУНЬ ЛУКОВЫЙ ЭКСТРАКТ КРАПИВЫ 150МЛ.", "ТВИНС ТЭК", 1, 150);
dt.Rows.Add("Магазин 1", 198767, "911-ШАМПУНЬ РЕПЕЙНЫЙ П/ВЫПАДЕНИЯ ВОЛОС 150МЛ.", "ТВИНС ТЭК", 1, 133);
dt.Rows.Add("Магазин 2", 198767, "911-ШАМПУНЬ РЕПЕЙНЫЙ П/ВЫПАДЕНИЯ ВОЛОС 150МЛ.", "ТВИНС ТЭК", 1, 136);
dt.Rows.Add("Магазин 3", 198767, "911-ШАМПУНЬ РЕПЕЙНЫЙ П/ВЫПАДЕНИЯ ВОЛОС 150МЛ.", "ТВИНС ТЭК", 1, 136);
dt.Rows.Add("Магазин 4", 198767, "911-ШАМПУНЬ РЕПЕЙНЫЙ П/ВЫПАДЕНИЯ ВОЛОС 150МЛ.", "ТВИНС ТЭК", 1, 140);
dt.Rows.Add("Магазин 5", 198767, "911-ШАМПУНЬ РЕПЕЙНЫЙ П/ВЫПАДЕНИЯ ВОЛОС 150МЛ.", "ТВИНС ТЭК", 2, 135);

var xml = new XElement("FF",
    dt.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(row => row["Code"])
        .Select(g =>
            new XElement("tov",
                new XElement("code", g.Key),
                new XElement("name", g.First()["Name"]),
                new XElement("producer", g.First()["Producer"]),
                new XElement("shops", g.Select(s =>
                    new XElement("shop",
                        new XAttribute("name", s["ShopName"]),
                        new XElement("quantity", s["Quantity"]),
                        new XElement("price", s["Price"])))))));

Console.WriteLine(xml);
```

Используем Linq to Xml. Группируем данные по колонке с кодом. Далее для каждой группы создаём элемент `tov`. В элементе `shops` итерируем сгруппированные данные и создаём элемент `shop` для каждого из них.

Лаконично, не правда ли?

Проверить онлайн: http://rextester.com/OWFH86445

Я не призываю всегда так делать. Подход с созданием моделей классов может быть более правильным, если они используются не только для промежуточного хранения с последующей сериализацией, но и для другой работы с ними. Но тогда стоит подумать об использовании ORM/MicroORM наподобие EF/Dapper и отказаться от `DataTable`.

Comment: согласен, отличное решение !

Answer (score 3):

Сделал так:

- описал классами структуру того, что нужно на выходе
- обходом по всему `DataTable` сформировал объекты и сереализовал их в XML

Вот такая структура на выходе:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "shop")]
public class Shop
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "quantity")]
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "shops")]
public class Shops
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "shop")]
    public List<Shop> Shop { get; set; }

    public Shops()
    {
        Shop = new List<Shop>();
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "tov")]
public class Tov
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "producer")]
    public string Producer { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "shops")]
    public Shops Shops { get; set; }

    public Tov()
    {
        Shops = new Shops();
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FF")]
public class FF
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "tov")]
    public List<Tov> Tov { get; set; }

    public FF()
    {
        Tov = new List<Tov>();
    }

    public string GetXMLFromObject()
    {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter tw = null;
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
            tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            serializer.Serialize(tw, this);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            sw.Close();
            if (tw != null)
            {
                tw.Close();
            }
        }
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

Вот так разбирал:

```
            DataTable tab = Sys.GetDataTable(query);
        if (tab.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            FF xml = new FF();
            int curtov, nexttov = 0;                

            for (int i = 0; i < tab.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Tov tov = new Tov();
                tov.Code = tab.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                tov.Name = tab.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString();
                tov.Producer = tab.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString();

                do
                {
                    curtov = Convert.ToInt32(tab.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString());
                    if ((i + 1) == tab.Rows.Count) { nexttov = 0; } else { nexttov = Convert.ToInt32(tab.Rows[i + 1].ItemArray[2].ToString()); }

                    Shop shop = new Shop();
                    shop.Name = tab.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                    shop.Quantity = tab.Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString();
                    shop.Price = tab.Rows[i].ItemArray[6].ToString();
                    tov.Shops.Shop.Add(shop);
                    i++;
                }
                while (curtov == nexttov);

                xml.Tov.Add(tov);
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\123.xml", xml.GetXMLFromObject());                 
        }
```

Comment: Если вы даёте ответ,  то он дллжен быть аргументирован.  Добавте ваш код прямо в ответ.

Comment: Выкладывайте свой код. Я почти уверен, что его можно очень сильно упростить.

Comment: @0xdb посмотрите, есть предложения как сделать проще ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov посмотрите, есть предложения как сделать проще ?